# How do I use regular expressions to parse HTML tags?

Tags: python, html, regex

Was wondering how I would extrapolate the value of an html element using a regular expression (in python preferably).

For example, `<a href="http://google.com"> Hello World! </a>`

What regex would I use to extract `Hello World!` from the above html?

Comment: Use python's html parsing abilities. (Right tool for the job.)

Comment: Please do not use regex to parse *ML.  Anyone that suggests that you should is wrong.

Comment: You stand in grave danger of getting your IDLE privileges revoked if you so much as touch XML/HTML with a regular expression.

Comment: @Nick: Yes, ML-derivates (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:ML_programming_language_family) are, like about all programming languages, way too complex to be parsed by regexes ;)

Comment: thanks @Mark :) you're the only person who gave a straight answer!

Comment: @James: Every time someone asks a question like this, a dozen people pop in and say it's a bad idea... I'll give you the benefit of the doubt and assume you weighed the pros and cons :) the "hello world" bit should be stored in `match.group(1)` if you use that pattern in `re.match`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Regex + HTML...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

But [**BeautifulSoup**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html) is a handy library.

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = '<a href="http://google.com"> Hello World! </a>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> soup.a.string
u' Hello World! '
```

---

This, for instance, would print out links on this page:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

q = urllib2.urlopen('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884419/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(q.read())

for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    if link.has_key('href'):
        print str(link.string) + " -> " + link['href']
    elif link.has_key('id'):
        print "ID: " + link['id']
    else:
        print "???"
```

Output:

```
Stack Exchange -> http://stackexchange.com
log in -> /users/login?returnurl=%2fquestions%2f3884419%2f
careers -> http://careers.stackoverflow.com
meta -> http://meta.stackoverflow.com
...
ID: flag-post-3884419
None -> /posts/3884419/revisions
...
```

Comment: if I had multipal links (<a href=""> blah blah </a>), that only seems to output the first link it comes across?

Comment: There are other methods. `soup.findAll('a')` for instance. See the documentation: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html

Comment: I keep hearing about BeautifulSoup but I didn't realize it actually had such a nice API... there are so many tools out there, but a lot of them are just atrocious to use. This is nice :) I've been doing my parsing in C# though.

Answer (score 8):

Using regex to parse HTML has been covered extensively on SO.  The consensus is that it shouldn't be done.

Here are some related links worth reading:

- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)
- http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

One trick I have used in the past to parse HTML files is convert it to XHTML and then treat it as an xml file and use xPath.  If this is an option look at:

- [HTML Tidy](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/)
- [SGML Reader](http://developer.mindtouch.com/SgmlReader)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you wouldn't use a Regular expression - they are unsuitable for most parsing tasks, including HTML.  Use a parsing library - I'm not an expert python user, but I'm sure there's one to be had.