# How would I make a simple URL extracter in Python?

Tags: python, hyperlink, web-crawler

How would I start on a single web page, let's say at the root of DMOZ.org and index every single url attached to it. Then store those links inside a text file. I don't want the content, just the links themselves. An example would be awesome.

Comment: Why do you need this in python? `wget` can do this without reinventing the wheel

Comment: I program on the best OS, Windows, not Linux :).

Comment: Multiple levels. An undetermined depth.

Comment: Wget is available for Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This, for instance, would print out links on [this very related (but poorly named) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884419/):

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

q = urllib2.urlopen('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884419/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(q.read())

for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    if link.has_key('href'):
        print str(link.string) + " -> " + link['href']
    elif link.has_key('id'):
        print "ID: " + link['id']
    else:
        print "???"
```

Output:

```
Stack Exchange -> http://stackexchange.com
log in -> /users/login?returnurl=%2fquestions%2f3884419%2f
careers -> http://careers.stackoverflow.com
meta -> http://meta.stackoverflow.com
...
ID: flag-post-3884419
None -> /posts/3884419/revisions
...
```

Comment: You should use `if 'href' in link:` rather than `link.has_key`. `has_key` is deprecated and removed from python 3.

Comment: For me (Py 2.6.5, BS 3.0.8) `'href' in link` returns `False`, even though `link['href']` will give me a URL.  I don't know that much about the workings of dictionaries though.  `'href' in zip(*link.attrs)[0]` does seem to work, but is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on reinventing the wheel, use an html parser like BeautifulSoup to grab all the  tags out. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499345/regular-expression-to-extract-url-from-an-html-link/499371#499371) to a similar question is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

[Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) is a Python framework for web crawling. Plenty of examples here: http://snippets.scrapy.org/popular/bookmarked/